# How to filter data based on the month and year value

Tags: pyspark, filter, callable

I am trying to filter data based on the month and year value in date column.

I converted my date column from string to date as

```
df.withColumn('ifrs_year_dt', to_date(unix_timestamp('ifrs_year_dr', 'Mm/dd/yyyy).cast('timestamp)))

df=df.withColumn('month',month(df['ifrs_year_dt]))
```

I am getting error int object is not callable, when using month() function. I tried it inside filter and its saying the same.

```
df=df.filter(month(df['ifrs_year_dt])==3)
```

And still getting the same error.

Comment: what is `month` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal working example that I think you can adapt to your needs:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
sample_dates = ['09/01/2021',
                '10/01/2021',
                '03/01/2021',
                '07/10/2010']
df = spark.createDataFrame([(date,) for date in sample_dates], ["ifrs_year_dr"])

df_with_date = df.withColumn('ifrs_year_dt', F.to_date(F.unix_timestamp('ifrs_year_dr', 'MM/dd/yyyy').cast('timestamp')))
df_with_month=df_with_date.withColumn('month',F.month(df_with_date['ifrs_year_dt']))
df_with_month.show()
df_with_month.filter(F.col("month") == 3).show()
```

output:

```
+------------+------------+-----+
|ifrs_year_dr|ifrs_year_dt|month|
+------------+------------+-----+
|  09/01/2021|  2021-09-01|    9|
|  10/01/2021|  2021-10-01|   10|
|  03/01/2021|  2021-03-01|    3|
|  07/10/2010|  2010-07-10|    7|
+------------+------------+-----+

+------------+------------+-----+
|ifrs_year_dr|ifrs_year_dt|month|
+------------+------------+-----+
|  03/01/2021|  2021-03-01|    3|
+------------+------------+-----+
```